# Git delete commit but don't delete the changes

Tags: git

I commited accidentally to much, I added the changes and wanted to do `git commit -m "foo"` but i mistyped me and typed `git commit -a -m "foo"`.

How can I revert this, without loosing the changes which I made?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `git reset HEAD^`. This will get rid of the most recent commit in your current branch but keep your working tree intact.

Note that this rewrites history. In case you already published that commit it and people pulled it, it's be better to *revert* the commit by creating a new commit using `git revert HEAD` that undoes the changes from the last commit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I wanted! I don't pushed the commit, everything is fine. If I already pushed it, I know how to revert it. ;)

Comment: Note that it won’t *“destroy”* the commit. It will just set the current branch to the previous commit making the “removed” commit disappear from the history of the branch. Other branches can still point to it (directly or indirectly) and the object will still stay there, unless really nothing points to it, and it is explicitely removed by Git’s garbage collection.